# How to run a powershell script with parameter value as HTML

Tags: html, powershell

I try to run a powershell script with some parameters / arguments at the start.
This script send mails out and works fine so far.
Now one of the start parameters of the script is the mail body. I hand over a HTML text from a file to this parameter.

As long as it is normal text, all is fine. 
If i try to add HTML formated text i receiv e exception in powershell like this:
"The '<' operator is reserved for future use."

`param(
   [string]$Body = "")`

If i call the script like this `myscript.ps1 -Body "this is plain text"` it works very well.

If i call the script like this `myscript.ps1 -Body "some HTML formated text"`
i receive the error

> "The '<' operator is reserved for future use."

How can i hand over HTML formatted text to a parameter of a powershell script?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I think you need to check the content of the file you are reading as text. Maybe the quoting is wrong in there?

Comment: Please provide some sample text input, non-formatted and html-formated text. Also, please show the command/line which throws the error.

Comment: Remember to back-tick any double-quotes in the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell have an escape character for special chars that it can't deal with.
It is: ` (grave-char)

Try the following code:

```
$htmlbody = $htmlbody -replace '<', '`'
```

Same thing for ">"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your code but I would approach your task to convert the string within the function to HTML format and then further work with it. I would suggest to use `ConvertTo-Html` and use its [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html?view=powershell-6).

```
Function New-HtmlDoc
{
  param
  (
    [string]$Body
  )
  $htmlBody = ConvertTo-Html -Body $Body

  Do-Something $htmlBody
}
```